# Why can't I move to the alternate file in Vim

Tags: vim

When I try to open two files in the same tab in Vim like so:

```
:e file1.txt

:e file2.txt

:previous

:next
```

I get `E163: There is only one file to edit`
 for both `:previous` and `:next` yet I can move to `file1.txt`
  using the command `:e #` which means there's an alternate file. 

*What could be the problem here?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

next and previous are used to traverse the argument list. You want `:bnext` (`:bn`) or `:bprevious` (`:bp`) to traverse the buffer list.

Comment: why did Bram and his pals feel the need to make an `argument list` and a `buffer list` seperate concepts and hence add two more  commands? It seems pointless.

Comment: @Segfault its because they were added at times. The argument list was from vi but the buffer list was added in vim. And they didn't really want to break any functionally from vi.

Comment: The things we do for backwards compatibility.